# Upgrade XenServer 6.5 to 7.1 - Supplemental Packages

Tags: dell-poweredge, xenserver, upgrade, iso, dell-openmanage

I'm planning on upgrading our **PowerEdge M620 servers from 6.5 to 7.1**. I read that the opemanage 8.1 also need to be reinstalled. I installed the opemanage server node 8.1 for the 6.5 install in order to get the **remote server power-on** feature working.

I can't find if any of the newer **OMSA** releases work for XenServer 7.1. I also can't find any available **isos** on the Dell site. Has anybody run into this issue upgrading from 6.5 to 7.1 with their supplemental packages (did they have to be reinstalled)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that only Dell ISM (which is a lightweight alternative to OMSA) is available for XenServer 7.x.

Dell iDRAC Service Module for XenServer, v2.4 [Download and information](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=PH2W0&fileId=3592196188&osCode=CXS07&productCode=poweredge-m630&languageCode=en&categoryId=SM)

I cannot find any information regarding remote power-on with ISM though.